# FullCalendar - JS Error in IE 8, Unknown Runtime Error

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm getting an "Unknown Runtime Error" in IE 8. It occurs at the statement "Ba[0].innerHTML=$" in the fullcalendar.min.js (latest version from Feb '11).

It's while trying to display an event. The event displays properly in Chrome and FF.

Here is the event data as it's retrieved from the JSON url:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"GroupHourAppointment","subject":"Test event","endAsIsoString":"2011-03-01T09:30:00","startAsIsoString":"2011-03-01T08:00:00","id":1,"color":3,"title":"Open"}]}
```

I've tried different date formats (with a "Z" appended to the end, for example) as well. If the date is "valid" it causes the error. Otherwise, the event is ignored and no error occurs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps someone else out there. I faced the same error in IE8 and ended up struggling with it. The solution was to change the following in version 1.5.3 of fullcalendar.min.js:

Change this: `P[0].innerHTML = e(i);`

To this: `$(P[0]).html(e(i));`

It seems that the strict innerHTML rules for IE8 were preventing the events from rendering.

Answer (score 0):

can you add this as a formal issue to the issue tracker?
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list

can you include your version of fullcalendar, as well as a **working** example. from the support page...

> please submit a report with a detailed description and a demonstration of the bug. This can be a link to a website or a ZIP containing a runnable HTML file. Please include everything needed to recreate the bug (JS, CSS, event JSON).

thanks!